# Pass a full url with Params in PHP

Tags: php, android

I want to pass a url as a parameter in my PHP script. The URL is coming from my Android app which passes a url and the PHP script custom formats XML to return to the app. So I would pass the url I wanted to format and the PHP script would do stuff and echo the results.

For instance I want to pass this url:

> differentwebpage.com/search/?query=ford%20f150&

in my php script (mywebpage.com/script.php):

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$str = file_get_contents($url);
echo $str;
```

So the full url would be:

> mywebpage.com/script.php?url=differentwebpage.com/search/?query=ford%20f150&

But this doesn't work. I think I need to URL encode/decode but I haven't had any success. How can I pass a full URL as a parameter?

Comment: [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a complete question. I'm passing from Android, is there a method similiar to that in Java?

Comment: @Nick http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: This has already been put in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding it in Android when you pass it.

You can encode using the `URLEncoder` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

You can then easily unencode it in PHP using `urldecode`.

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$str = file_get_contents($url);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the php function `urlencode()`. It will encode the URL in your example like this:

```
differentwebpage.com%2Fsearch%2F%3Fquery%3Dford%2520f150%26
```

Which can be fully decoded. And only contains characters that are valid in a URL.

Comment: He is passing it from Android to PHP, so he should be using `urldecode` in PHP and `URLEncoder` in Android.