# PHP store url including some GET parameters inside ONE GET parameter

Tags: php, variables, parameters, get, escaping

Given is a string containing an url, like this:

```
$referer = 'https://www.example.com/page.php?firstparameter=value&secondparameter=value2';
```

Then, there is a link **containing the $referer** variable from above, as an individual GET parameter at the end of the link:

**Link 1:**

```
<a href="https://www.example.org/site.php?parameter1=somevalue&parameter2=somevalue&referer=<?php echo $referer; ?>">Linktext</a>
```

So I want to store and transfer the whole url of the first **$referer** variable through one GET variable inside the **Link 1** above.

When opening that link, it should be possible to output just the "referer" parameter, including all the original GET parameters inside that parameter, so the output is the same as the original $referer, like this:

```
echo $_GET['referer'];
```

**Desired output:**

```
https://www.example.com/page.php?firstparameter=value&secondparameter=value2
```

I see it problematic due to the several get parameters **inside** the one "referer" get parameter, and I don't know a common way how to sanatize or escape them, (or however the process is called in this case), so they don't get interpreted as individual get parameters of the parent get parameter.

Thank you.

Comment: `<?= htmlspecialchars(urlencode($referer)) ?>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a full url with Params in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188610/pass-a-full-url-with-params-in-php)

Comment: @miken32 Yes indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the functions urlencode and urldecode do what I am looking for.

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188610/pass-a-full-url-with-params-in-php)